# Fill a bytearray of known size from generator

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, performance, out-of-memory

Outgoing from a formerly given or computed very long array (MB, GB, TB) of small bytesize numbers (so I use a `bytearray`), I need to compute in an next iteration step a follow-up `bytearray`. It is possible to compute the size which is needed for next iteration step `bytearray`, so I can allocate the memory beforehand by using one of the constructors for `bytearray`:

```py
# A is the current/former bytearray
# sizes of array: 1 -> 2 -> 8 -> 48 -> 480 -> 5_760 -> 92_160 -> 1_658_880 -> 
# 36_495_360 -> 1_021_870_080 -> 30_656_102_400 [ -> 1_103_619_686_400 ... ]
ls = NextLenArray(A)
L = bytearray(ls)

# generator will create new values out of the current existing
for i,j in enumerate(gen_values(A)):
    L[i] = j

# need to assign it back into A for next iteration
A = L
```

Alternatively, it's obvious to create directly the next `bytearray` by using generator inside comprehension. I don't know how and when (stepwise?) reservation of memory will happen.

```py
A = bytearray(j for j in gen_values(A))
```

It looks like that it runs a little faster, but monitoring task manager it uses more memory while generating and in later iteration steps it get stopped one step earlier caused be `MemoryError`.

Is there an easy way to combine the pre-reservation by assigning a `bytearray` with needed size and use this with generator/comprehension-list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like that it runs a little faster, but monitoring task manager it uses more memory while generating and in later iteration steps it get stopped one step earlier caused be MemoryError.

This is because **generator does not have a well known length**. Python cannot iterate over the generator to know its length because it would be consumed. So it need to **resize the bytearray on the fly** more or less efficiently. Regarding the *implementation* (eg. dynamic array with a growing size or a dynamic array of independent big chunks), this can require *significantly more memory* than just allocating a bytearray directly at the good size. On my machine, with CPython 3.9.2, I *cannot reproduce* your problem because it uses memory efficient implementation.

> Is there an easy way to combine the pre-reservation by assigning a bytearray with needed size and use this with generator/comprehension-list?

Yes, you can using a **chunk-based copy**. Here is an example:

```py
import itertools

ls = NextLenArray(A)
L = bytearray(ls)
gen = gen_values(A)
chunkSize = 65536

for i in range(0, ls, chunkSize):
    # Copy a chunk. This can (and does) allocate memory because of a 
    # potential internal copy. But the amount is bounded by the chunk size.
    L[i:i+chunkSize] = itertools.islice(gen, chunkSize)
```

---

Note that manipulating huge amount of memory in pure Python is not efficient (especially with CPython). Consider using high-performance Python packages such as Numpy and Numba or writing some parts in a native language like C or C++ (using for example Cython). Alternatively, you could be interested in using PyPy.

Comment: thanks - helped a lot - one question:at begin the bytearray is very small so I used for defining the size: chunksize = min(65536, ls) - I compared some varying numbers with different length of array - it seems that it shouldn't be too small (1KB) but no really win in performance for 1MB chunks - data was up to 1GB